# Angular 4 with KeyCloak stuck in login loop (Access Control)

Tags: angular, access-control, keycloak

I integrated KeyCloak to my Angular app. Once I run the app, I get redirected to the KeyCloak login. So far so good. If I enter wrong username / password, it will tell me that its wrong. Once I put in the correct credentials, it redirects me to my app but then It just keeps refreshing and refreshing. It seems that it's sending a login request every second.

Here is what log gives me:

[image]

I am sure that the problem is not in the logic of the code, but maybe in configuration. I googled the error and saw that things like changing

```
localhost:8080
```

to

```
127.0.0.1:8080
```

could fix the problem, but it didn't do anything in my case.

Comment: Just checked the docs on KeyCloak, and I couldn't find any posts from anyone saying they were able to connect KeyCloak w/ Angular's Router.

Comment: What is your client setting called *Web Origins* in Keycloak? It should be set to `*`.

Comment: @Yuri it is set to *

Comment: @masterfan OK, then you can try setting directly `http://localhost:4300` instead of the `*`.

Comment: How did you integrate it, if I might ask?

Comment: @dalu I created my own KeyCloakService, and Login & Logout components which use that service and redirect accordingly. It works without any problems now.

Comment: Did u fix this problem ?

Comment: @Chandru I did, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with KeyCloak setup. It was in

> app.module.ts

In one of my services I had HashLocationStrategy instead of PathLocationStrategy.

```
-    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
+    useClass: PathLocationStrategy
```

So my providers look something like this now:

```
providers: [
  KeyCloakService,
  AssetService,
    {
     provide: LocationStrategy,
     useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something was happening to me too. Try disabling cors on the browser ([Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)) or set the Web Origin set in keycloak