# How do I solve the keycloak refresh /#state on my angular7 project - i'm using keycloak-angular

Tags: keycloak, angular7

I have also tried all varying combinations for web origins and valid redirect URIs

[image: keycloak realm]I login via keycloak and it continuously redirects me back and forth between my localhost application and this url: http://localhost:4200/#state=166446fd-daf6-4b76-b595-583c01c663df&session_state=57ead1f3-bf41-4117-9ddf-75e37c9248e7&code=8692b58b-0868-4762-b82e-acde9911dd34.57ead1f3-bf41-4117-9ddf-75e37c9248e7.1e8b5b9d-b590-453e-b396-62b46c18cc9f

I have tried it on firefox and chrome but with the same issue - it seems to be looking for the keycloak.json file in the network tab even though I can login to the correct realm via keycloak

**GET http://localhost:4200/keycloak.json 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969**

**ERROR An error happened during Keycloak initialization. core.js:1601**

**Unhandled Promise rejection: An error happened during Keycloak initialization. ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: An error happened during Keycloak initialization. undefined**

```
static init(): Promise<any> {
    const keycloakAuth: any = Keycloak({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
        realm: 'ContractPortal',
        clientId: 'secretkey2',
        'ssl-required': 'external',
        'public-client': true
    });

    KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        keycloakAuth.init({onLoad: 'login-required'})
            .success(() => {
                console.log(keycloakAuth);
                KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
                KeycloakService.auth.authz = keycloakAuth;
                KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl
                    + '/realms/angular_keycloak/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri='
                    + document.baseURI;
                resolve();
            })
            .error(() => {
                reject();
            });
    });
}
```

it'd be great if one of you guys can point me in the right direction to solve this issue...

I have found another similar question to what I have asked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014413/angular-4-with-keycloak-stuck-in-login-loop-access-control) but not sure how to implement this solution! this is my provider setup -
`providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializer,
            multi: true,
            deps: [KeycloakService]
        }
    ],`

but **OP** puts the following in his provider 
`providers: [
  KeyCloakService,
  AssetService,
    {
     provide: LocationStrategy,
     useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    }
  ]`

Please let me know if you require any other information

Answer (score 4):

For anybody that ran into the same issue - I misunderstood the keycloak.json file and did not know where to get it - so I was exporting the complete json file from keycloak but THIS is not how you should get it!!

First you have to go to your realm > clients and click on installation

[image]

- then download the keycloak OIDC json file
- then place it next to the index.html file in your application

This solved my issue - hope it helps somebody else

Answer (score 0):

I was researching on the internet and it is the same case, for me my angular page is reloading automatically in infnite loop

I did some changes in keycloak-init.ts file (please find following code and change checkLoginIframe from true to false)
Old Code: keycloak.init ({onLoad: 'login-required', "checkLoginIframe": true})
New Code: keycloak.init ({onLoad: 'login-required', "checkLoginIframe": false})

Answer (score 0):

```
this.loadingService.isLoading$.pipe(delay(100)).subscribe((data => {
      this.loading = data
    }))

    this.isLogging = await this.keycloak.isLoggedIn();
    type roleUser = Array<{ id: number, text: string }>
    if (this.isLogging) {
      this.userProfile = await this.keycloak.loadUserProfile();
      this.userRoles = await this.keycloak.getUserRoles();
    }else { 
      // this.clearSession();
    }
```

- if you are using "this.keycloak.loadUserProfile()" Remove this "clear session"